# Python Bulbs framework example of fget argument in a bulbs object init method

Tags: python, tinkerpop, bulbs

What is the scope of the `fget=` argument upon initialization of a Bulbs class property?

For instance when I am writing:

```
from bulbs.model import Node, Relationship
from bulbs.property import String

class foobar(Node)
   element_type = "foobar"
   fget_property = String(fget=some_method)
```

What `some_method` should be to get for the fget_property to be properly defined? Should it perform some operation on the other class properties or can it also be a function of the relations that are liked to an instance of the class, for instance something calling `self.outV(some_relation)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the value for `fget` should be a method name that returns a calculated value. The method name should reference a method defined in your Bulbs Model class, and the method should have no parameters.

The `fget` method gets called every time you create/update/save the element to the database.

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L347

Bulbs uses a Python Metaclass to set the `fget` function as a *Python* `property` on the `Model` `class` you are defining (not to be confused with the Bulbs database `Property`, such as `String` in your example).

See Python class property (little "p") vs Bulbs database Property (big "P")...

- Python class property https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property
- Bulbs database Property http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/property/

Here's how `fget` is set on the Bulbs `Model` you define:

```
class ModelMeta(type):
    """Metaclass used to set database Property definitions on Models."""

    def __init__(cls, name, base, namespace):
        """Store Property instance definitions on the class as a dictionary.""" 

        # Get inherited Properties
        cls._properties = cls._get_initial_properties()

        # Add new Properties
        cls._register_properties(namespace)

    ### ...other class methods snipped for brevity... ###

    def _initialize_property(cls, key, property_instance):
        """
        Set the Model class attribute based on the Property definition.

        :param key: Class attribute key
        :type key: str

        :param property_instance: Property instance
        :type property_instance bulbs.property.Property

        """
        if property_instance.fget:
            fget = getattr(cls, property_instance.fget)
            # TODO: implement fset and fdel (maybe)
            fset = None
            fdel = None
            property_value = property(fget, fset, fdel)
        else:
            property_value = None
        setattr(cls, key, property_value)
```

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L97

For an overview of how Metaclasses work in Python, see:

- "Metaclasses Demystified" 
  http://web.archive.org/web/20120503014702/http://cleverdevil.org/computing/78/
- [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

UPDATE: Here is a complete working example of a model declaration using an `fget` method...

```
# people.py    

from bulbs.model import Node, Relationship                                                                                                                                                                                                    
from bulbs.property import String, Integer, DateTime                                                                                                                                                                                          
from bulbs.utils import current_datetime

class Person(Node):  

    element_type = "person" 

   name = String(nullable=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    age = Integer("calc_age")                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    def calc_age(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        """A pointless method that calculates a hard-coded age."""                                                                                                                                                                            
        age = 2014 - 1977                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        return age                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class Knows(Relationship):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    label = "knows" 

    timestamp = DateTime(default=current_datetime, nullable=False)
```

And here's a full working example for how to use it...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> from people import Person, Knows                                                                                                                                                                                                              

>>> g = Graph()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> g.add_proxy("people", Person)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> g.add_proxy("knows", Knows)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

>>> james = g.people.create(name="James")                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> julie = g.people.create(name="Julie")                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> knows = g.knows.create(james, julie)                                                                                                                                                                                                          

>>> print james.age
37                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>>> print knows.timestamp
2014-08-04 21:28:31
```

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of actual `fget` function declaration and usage? It seems so far that if a new, user-defined method was to be introduced as a new `fget`, this would require inserting it into the `Model` class or relevant subclass, such as `String`, would it?